# How to use an Android stock app as a library in another custom Android app?

Tags: android

I have downloaded Android source code and set up a build environment. 
I want to use the Android stock Mms app as a library from my custom app, so that I can use the functionalities of Mms. So, I modified the Android.mk file of the Mms app by including the BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY template, and build it (by $ mmm packages/apps/Mms) to generate a "MmsLib.so" file. 
Then, in my custom app's make file, I have LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := MmsLib.so, to refer to the Mms shared lib. But when I build my custom app, it throws error as it cannot find symbols for classes of Mms lib.
Any help is appreciaited !

Answer (score 1):

There is no native code in [the current AOSP copy of the MMS application](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms). Hence, your `MmsLib.so` file is probably empty.

You are welcome to take the Android project and attempt to turn it into an Android library project. However, it is unlikely that this will work, as the AOSP applications are only designed to be built as part of a full firmware build, not as a standalone Android SDK project, let alone an Android library project.